# The required code of this code cannot be accessed with CursorWindow

Tags: sqlite, android-studio, android-cursor

This code gives an error when running the application as
follows
E/CursorWindow: Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a
CursorWindow which has 5 rows, 5 columns.

```
    ........
    public ArrayList<picture> getallpic() {
    ArrayList<picture> pictueres = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor cur = database.rawQuery("select * From " + 
   MyDatabase.table, null);
    if (cur != null && cur.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            String id = 
      cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(MyDatabase.id));


       String soraname = 
    cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(MyDatabase.name));
        String place = 
      cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(MyDatabase.place));
        String date = 
    cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(MyDatabase.date));
        String pict = 
      cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(MyDatabase.pict));
        picture pic = new picture(id, soraname, place, date, pict);
        pictueres.add(pic);
    }
    while (cur.moveToNext());
    cur.close();
   }
   return pictueres;
 }
```

..........
When running the application it gives the previous error with accurate coding

Comment: One of the `MyDatabase.x` columns does not exist in the table.

Comment: Wow! The error was in the name of one of the database blinds and now it works